# VBA how to find the last empty cell after an active 1

Tags: excel, vba, uipath

I want to fill in the time in the next empty cell , but the fucntion End(xlUp) takes me to the last active cell , and the End(xlDown) takes me to the last cell of the chart.

What do I do? Please help me

Here's the code I wrote to find the last cell of column "F" .

```
Function insertTime()

Range("F").End (xlUp)  = Now()

End Function
```

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qqWd.png)

Answer (score 1):

If your sheet is empty then it will take to last row. If you have data in `F Column` then it will take to the last cell. Try below codes

```
Sub insertTime()
    Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Now()
End Sub
```

Comment: throws an exepction Invoke VBA: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800ADF09

Comment: Do you have any data to `F1`, `F2`, `F3.....` cells?

Comment: i only have a header and also f2 that is in use

Comment: @meytal Then try my edited answer. It will be `Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Now()`.

Comment: still gives the same exepction... what do i do im gonna cry ive been working on this for 3 days

Comment: I have tested it and just working fine to me. Can you share your workbook via google drive so that can check.

Comment: How you are triggering the function?

Comment: i added an image in the edited snippet please have a look

Comment: Test it in excel first. Then try to automate.

Comment: @meytal Then please mark the answer as accepted (tick mark it).

Answer (score 0):

`Offset()` to the rescue: where-ever you are, you can use `Offset()` to move one cell to the left (`Offset(0,-1)`), to the right (`Offset(0,1)`), up (`Offset(-1,0)`) or down (`Offset(1,0)`), and obviously you can use other numbers: `Offset(1,2)`, `Offset(2,-1)`, ... are ways to jump around like a horse on a chessboard :-)

For your application, I believe that this (or a similar one) might help you:

Go up and to the right:

```
Range("F:F").End (xlUp).Offset(0,1)  = Now()
```

Go down and one deeper:

```
Range("F1").End (xlDown).Offset(1,0)  = Now()
```

...

Comment: `Offset(0,1)` will refer one cell right of last non empty cell. May be it would `Offset(1,0)`

Comment: this 1 also throws the same expection Invoke VBA: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800ADF09

Comment: @meytal: I'm sorry. I just based my code on yours without paying attention. You need to use a correct range, like `Range(F:F)` or `Range("F1")` in order to make it work.